# How can I check if my UEFI supports RAID?

Tags: motherboard, bios, raid, uefi

I can't find it in UEFI settings. Motherboard name is ASRock Z370 Pro4.
I had a look at the specification at the manufacturer's site however all the info they provide is:

- 128Mb AMI UEFI Legal BIOS with multilingual GUI support
- ACPI 6.0 Compliant wake up events
- SMBIOS 2.7 Support
- DRAM, PCH 1.0V, VCCIO, VCCST, VCCSA, VPPM Voltage Multi-adjustment

IF i don't have that support do I need new MB to be able to create hardware RAID? (Not windows one)

I will appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need either a new motherboard or add a RAID controller to the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

This MB seems to support RAID. You should be able to enable it in the 'BIOS' (UEFI) Settings (F2 at boot), Go to Advanced, Storage Config, then set SATA to RAID mode.

- I would recommend a 5-6 disk setup with RAID 5, if you have the space and power for it.
- You *may* want to have the OS on a separate disk (SSD?), shielded from the RAID.
- Or, you could use just a simple mirror setup. (RAID 1)

The details for this setup can be found in this manual; http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/RAID/Z370%20Pro4/English.pdf